# JOOQ failed to generate souces if pojo and DAO was in same package

Tags: java, maven, jooq, querydsl, jooq-codegen-maven

My pojo(JPA entities) and DAO was in same package, I configured jooq-codegen-maven to generate TableImpl code  from JPA entities. and DAO's code uses TableImpl.

the strange thing is ,

1. when the first time I compile (`mvn clean` and `install`), the codegen will fetch  **0 tables** . And my DAO will get **compile error (unknown class)** because the TableImpl was not created. And the compile process of JPA entities(in same package) was skipped.
2. Now, If I comment-out all DAO code and compile. Jooq also fetch 0 tables, but the other code of the package (including 9 JPA entities) will compile success
3. I have to compile again, Jooq will fetch **9 tables**, and generate theirs TableImpl.
4. now I can un-comment the DAO, and compile again, finally everything will success. (Apparently, It's not an option to compile a project for three times).

If I change to QueryDSL (using apt-maven-plugin), it will success in the first time. Seems like QueryDSL first create Q-class and then compile the other code, but Jooq only generate code depends on a fully success compile, which is impossible. just like a dead-lock.

My pom.xml:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jooq-codegen</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <generator>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.jpa.JPADatabase</name>
                            <inputSchema>PUBLIC</inputSchema>
                            <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
                            
                            <properties> 
                                <property>
                                    <key>packages</key>
                                    <value>com.mypack.business</value>
                                </property>
 
                                <property>
                                    <key>useAttributeConverters</key>
                                    <value>true</value>
                                </property> 
                                <property>
                                    <key>unqualifiedSchema</key>
                                    <value>none</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </database>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>com.mypack.business.repository.entity.jooq</packageName>
                            <directory>target/generated-sources/java</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

So how can I make Jooq compile success for just one time?

Or, if it's difficult, can I spread pojo and DAO (including jooq codegen) into two project to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented in the manual page of the [`JPADatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa/). The `JPADatabase` doesn't use any annotation processing hook into the compilation process and generate your `TableImpl`. Instead, it uses previously compiled entities and runs Hibernate DDL generation on them. That means, you *have to* compile your entities *first*, and only then generate your jOOQ code, and only then compile your DAO. See the manual section on how to organise your dependencies:

```
                +-------------------+
                | Your JPA entities |
                +-------------------+
                     ^         ^
          depends on |         | depends on
                     |         |
  +---------------------+   +---------------------+
  | jOOQ codegen plugin |   | Your application    |
  +---------------------+   +---------------------+
                     |         |
           generates |         | depends on
                     v         v
             +-------------------------+
             | jOOQ generated classes  |
             +-------------------------+
```

If you think about what happens behind the scenes, that appears to be a much cleaner approach than relying on annotation processing's various caveats and limitations caused by the fact that they *have to* happen during compilation.

JPA entities are self-contained, and can be designed as a re-usable libraries for various other componnents. DAOs will depend on both JPA entities and/or jOOQ code, and other lower level stuff.